# Is it true that the slope of a vertical line times the slope of a horizontal like don't equal $-1$, even though they're perpendicular?

Tags: infinity

I know that the slopes of two lines that are perpendicular have a value of $-1$ when multiplied because they're opposite reciprocals (e.g. $5$ and $-{1\over 5}$), but what if there's a horizontal and a vertical line ($x=3$ and $y=-2$).  They're perpendicular, too, but a vertical line has no slope, so about $0\cdot\infty$, that would be undefined, right?  Well, infinity is undefined, so that's why a vertical line has no slope.  I also think this is why that silly problem is undefined and doesn't always equal zero.  Well, what's the slope of a vertical line times the slope of a horizontal line?  Tell me what you think!

Comment: Slope of vertical line is "undefined", so it is true that when you multiply it by zero you do not get $-1$.

Comment: That makes me wonder if there is any real-valued function $f$ that can be defined on the real projective line such that there is some constant $c$ so that for all perpendicular $a$ and $b$ one has $f(a)f(b) = c$. I suppose not.

Comment: @MJD sure there is. Any constant function will work.

Comment: Of course.  I originally had $-1$ instead of $c$, which rules out a constant function, and then replaced $-1$ with $c$ without specifying that $c$ should be negative.